# Why Does OpenCV Resize Give Different Pixel Values When Specifying Dsize vs. fx/fy?

Tags: python, opencv

Today I was surprised to discover that when using OpenCV-Python `cv2.resize`, I get different results from when I specify `fx` and `fy`, or when I do the `dsize` calculation myself and feed that.

Note that this is NOT about image size mismatch, but actual individual pixel value difference.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

scale = 0.55
image = np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10).astype(np.float)
resized_fx_fy = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=scale, fy=scale, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
resize_height, resize_width = resized_fx_fy.shape
resized_dsize = cv2.resize(image, (resize_width, resize_height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
print(np.abs(resized_fx_fy - resized_dsize).max())
```

```
7.499998092651367
```

```
print(resized_fx_fy - resized_dsize)
```

```
[[0.83333344 0.98484851 1.13636362 1.28787897 1.43939408 1.09090917]
 [2.34848631 2.50000024 2.65151525 2.80303049 2.9545455  2.6060605 ]
 [3.86363742 4.01515031 4.16666532 4.31818056 4.46969557 4.12121058]
 [5.37879091 5.53030276 5.68181777 5.83333302 5.98484802 5.63636303]
 [6.89394202 7.04545283 7.19696784 7.34848309 7.49999809 7.1515131 ]
 [3.40909298 3.5606029  3.71211791 3.86363316 4.01514816 3.66666317]]
```

From a naive interpretation of the opencv docs, these should be equivalent but clearly they are not.

A possible hint: The above code yields no difference when `scale = 0.5`

In case it's relevant:

```
Python 3.8.5

opencv-contrib-python     4.2.0.34                 pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python             4.2.0.34                 pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python-headless    4.5.1.48                 pypi_0    pypi
```

Comment: It's also OK for scales of 0.6, 0.7 ... anything where the scale exactly matches the ratio of input/output (without rounding). I haven't checked the code, but I'd say that when you specify destination size, it first calculates `fx` and `fy` and then uses those for the actual resize. In which case you're comparing scale of 0.55 with scale of 0.6 both sampled into a 6x6 array.

Comment: How about RGB image case? I see your example is floating point value. I wonder it could be different in integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv::resize` is an affine transformation that maps integer indices from the destination image to floating point indices in the source image and uses the interpolation method to calculate the value. Because it is an affine transformation, the scale parameter is the most important parameter in determining the exact output values.

According to the OpenCV [source code for cv::resize()](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/68d15fc62edad980f1ffa15ee478438335f39cc3/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp#L4052), if `dsize` is provided, `fx` and `fy` (referred to as `inv_scale_x` and `inv_scale_y` in c++ source code) are overwritten with relative scale of output to input, regardless of whether `fx` or `fy` are zero or not. In your example, the first `cv.resize()` uses `inv_scale_x` and `inv_scale_y` of 0.55. The second `cv.resize()` uses 0.6 for these two scale parameters.

Comment: That would explainn why 0.5 generates identical images, because the output will be 5x5 and `5/10==0.5`.